# how to search xml file , in condition that file name is inside the file

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk, find

how to search xml file , in condition that file name is inside the file

**first task**

so first to search the file with xml type we do:

```
find /tmp -name '*.xml'

/tmp/Prepare_file_Env.xml
```

**second task**

the second part is to find  filename - **Prepare_file_Env word** is inside the file - **Prepare_file_Env.xml**  ,

so I did this

example:

```
grep -cq Prepare_file_Env Prepare_file_Env.xml ; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo $FileName
```

my quastion - how to combain the two tasks in one find syntax

syntax of requested find ... , or any other solution ....

```
find /tmp -name '*.xml' -exec ............
```

example of the xml file - **Prepare_file_Env.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Component configuration file -->
<Component>
   <Name>Prepare_file_Env</Name>
```

**expected results from find CLI, based on the XML file** example

```
/tmp/Prepare_file_Env.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $ find . -type f -name '*.xml' -exec grep -o -P '(?<=<Name>).*(?=</Name>)' {} \;
 Prepare_file_Env
```

In summary:

`grep -o -P` uses the special `Perl` type regex match and gets the word between `<Name>` and `</Name>` for the `xml` file found by `find`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find /tmp -name '*\.xml' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 sh -c 'grep -l `sed "s:^.*/::;s:.xml *$::"<<<"$@"` "$@"' echo

/tmp/Prepare_file_Env.xml
```

---

1. `sed "s:^.*/::;s:.xml *$::"<<<"$@"`: get the base filename without `.xml`
2. `grep -l`: print file name if string found

Comment: not good , because Prepare_file_Env is a variable !!  , this variable should get tne file name ( without the .xml )

Comment: @enodmilvado: ok get it at last; the `grep` now find the filename, not a predefine string